# Outputting a very large file to csv

Tags: r

I am trying to output a matrix( 3,000,000 rows X 16,000 columns) using

```
write(mat,"C:/Users/bjen/Desktop/Science/mat.csv")
```

but I am getting an error:

```
Error in asMethod(object) : 
  Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105
```

Any ideas how to output large matrices? This is a SparseMatrix by the way.

Comment: write.matrix() from MASS package? I would guess your `mat` is already a matrix

Comment: BTW, do you really need CSV? Binary options might be a lot faster/compact

Comment: Well, IIRC `readr` package might be worth checking as well

Comment: If this really is a sparse matrix then the Matrix-package has `writeMM` although then it would be an object of class 'sparseMatrix' rather than what you wrote.

Comment: This is a sparseMatric. I don't necessarily need csv but what do you mean by binary options.